# UML - Caso de Uso

Tags: modelagem, uml, casos-de-uso

Olá, estou como uma dúvida sobre a elaboração de um caso de uso, e gostaria de saber se posso aplicar Generalização/Especificação em casos de usos ou é apenas nos atores?

Exemplo 1 (Sem Generalização/Especificação)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso de uso, o Ator funcionário poderá realizar a reserva de Auditório, Coffee e Eventos, e todas elas precisam verificar disponibilidade, Registrar e emitir email. Minha dúvida é, posso usar a generalização/especificação para que esses três casos de uso (Reservar Auditorio, Agendar Coffee e Agendar Evento) herdem os includes (Verificar Disponibilidade, Registrar Solicitação e Emitir Email)? Assim diminuir o número de linhas de include.

Exemplo 2 (Herdando Caso de Uso):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Att,

Comment: Eses casos de uso _Reservar Auditório_, _Agendar Coffee_ e _Agendar Evento_ seriam <<extends>>, não?

Comment: Mas porque seriam extend?

Comment: > Quando o caso de uso B estende o caso de uso A, significa que quando o caso de uso A for executado o caso de uso B poderá (poderá – talvez não seja) ser executado também. A direção do relacionamento é do caso de uso extensor (aqui o caso de uso B) para o caso de uso estendido (aqui o caso de uso A). Fonte: https://www.ateomomento.com.br/caso-de-uso-include-extend-e-generalizacao/

Comment: Não consegui entender direito, mas vou entrar nesse link que você mando. Obrigado!!
Mas deixa eu explicar melhor o que ocorre no caso de uso:
Se um desses três casos é executado, obrigatoriamente o caso de uso "Verificar Disponibilidade" é executado também, tornando ele uma sub-rotina. 
Então sempre que ocorrer alguma reserva, deverá ocorrer uma verificação de disponibilidade.
Ainda confundo a utilização do Extend e Incluide.

Comment: Eu acho os nomes "extends" e "includes" péssimos para a compreensão em português. Troco mentalmente por "complementa" e "requer" e fica tudo certo. Pelo menos para mim é isso que eles fazem: o includes é requerido pelo caso de uso e o extends complementa o caso de uso (de maneira opcional). Isso também evita a confusão com o "estender" de herança, como tem no Java.